# SQL ordering - select top rows within top rows

Tags: sql, hive, limit

Apologies for the crappy title - wasn't able to come up with something better.

I have the following table:

```
Customer_ID    Item_ID        sale_ID   sale_TS
103293         I-0394039    S-430943    20161101
```

I need to find the top 100 customers with the most sales and for each of them, the top 100 items that they've purchased in a given timeframe. This is what I have so far:

```
select vs.Customer_ID, vs.Item_ID, count(*) count2
from sales.sales_import si1
join
(
    select Customer_ID, count(*) s_count2 from sales.sales_import where
    sale_TS between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-31' group by Customer_ID order by sale_TS desc limit 100
)
si2
on si1.Customer_ID = si2.Customer_ID
where
si1.sale_TS between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-31'
group by  vs.Customer_ID, vs.Item_ID
order by vs.Customer_ID, count2 desc limit 100
```

Questions:

- I'm essentially joining the table to itself here, is there a better way?
- How do I limit the query to return only the top 100 items per Customer_ID? The outer limit here will limit all rows and not the first X per customerID

Answer (score 0):

Try the row_number function. You'll have to build out 2 derived tables (subqueries used in the FROM clause). One for the customers, and one for their items. Inner join the subqueries so you only get the items from the customers returned in the first derived table.

```
select * from
--get your top 100 customers
  (select * from 
     (select Customer_ID, row_number() OVER (order by sale_TS) as rank
     from sales_import
     where sale_TS between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-31'
     group by Customer_ID)
   where rank <= 100) custs
 --now build out a derived table that picks out the top 100 items they purchased using the same method
```

(select blah blah blah from (select blah blah blah)) items

```
   --now inner join your 2 derived tables
where custs.Customer_ID, = items.Customer_ID
```

Comment: the rank here would simply get you a row number based on the Sale_TScolumn nothing to do with the number of sales.